# Magento 2: How to get encrypted config value?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I am making a custom form plugin that integrates ReCaptcha in Magento 2.

To integrate ReCaptcha in the frontend I am trying to read ReCaptcha v3 public key (`recaptcha_frontend/type_recaptcha_v3/public_key`) from the system configuration using `ScopeConfigInterface` interface in Block template like this.

```php
<?php

namespace Vendor\CustomForm\Block;

use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class Template extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    private const XML_PATH_RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY = 'recaptcha_frontend/type_recaptcha_v3/public_key';

    protected $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function getReCaptchaPublicKey(): string
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(static::XML_PATH_RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE);
    }
}
```

And accessing it in the `block.phtml` like this.

```php
<?php echo $block->getReCaptchaPublicKey(); ?>
```

But instead of the public key, I get the following output.

```php
$this->helper('Vendor\Module\Helper\Data')->getConfig('section/group/field');
```

Any help would be appreciated!

UPDATE: I did try using `EncryptorInterface` but no luck!

```php
<?php

namespace Vendor\CustomForm\Block;

use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class Template extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    private const XML_PATH_RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY = 'recaptcha_frontend/type_recaptcha_v3/public_key';

    protected $scopeConfig;
    protected $encryptor;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface $encryptor,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->encryptor = $encryptor;
    }

    public function getReCaptchaPublicKey(): string
    {
        $key = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(static::XML_PATH_RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE);
        return $this->encryptor->decrypt($key);
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of `core_config_data` table. I trying to access the value with the path `recaptcha_frontend/type_recaptcha_v3/public_key`.

[image: Screenshot of core_config_data table]

Comment: This may not directly answer the question but it does answer your problem. If you are echoing the key in a phtml template, there is no need to encrypt it.

Comment: Also, post the field configuration from your system.xml Did you try to echo the value without decrypting? I suspect that your value is either not decrypted or you have a different crypt key in your env.php than what was used to encrypt it

Comment: Thanks btw! I did try echoing without decrypting but it didn't work. Also, my plugin doesn't have a system.xml.

Comment: Also, no issue with crypt value in env.php, since these are freshly saved values in system configuration.

Comment: So you're storing the value in config.xml but no field is configured in system.xml? Try adding backend_model to your field in config.xml

<recpatcha_token backend_model="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Encrypted"/>

Comment: No, I am not storing anything from my module. 

I just trying to access Magento's default system configuration value located at Store > Configurations > Security > Google reCAPTCHA Storefront > reCAPTCHA v3 Invisible > Google API Website Key.

Which is stored in 'core_config_data' table at 'recaptcha_frontend/type_recaptcha_v3/public_key'.

Comment: Try flushing the config cache if it is a fresh token. php bin/magento cache:flush config. Also, as a sanity check, remove `ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE` to see if you get a global or default value

Comment: Also, you don't really need to pass a scope such as `ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE` anyway. When you call scopeConfig->getValue, Magento already knows what the store context is and will give you the proper value

Comment: Just did! Still no luck! Thanks btw!

Comment: It works for paths like `web/unsecure/base_url` but not with `recaptcha_frontend/type_recaptcha_v3/public_key`.

Comment: Post a screenshot of the full row from your database. It sounds like something isn't right. It should be working.

Comment: Sure! Updated the question.

Comment: Everything here sounds correct. You may want to debug all the way back to the query to the database to see whats happening.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it.